# 5bit signed magnitude comparator

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, comparator, binary

[image]

I know how to compare unsigned binary numbers.

But can you help me compare any signed binary numbers?

Above is my simulation but I don't know how to integrate those signed bits in my circuit correctly. In that setup, my output also reads my signed bit as one of the input not as a polarity.

Comment: Signed values use msb as the polarity. Do you know resolution of lsb in each case? I use lower case for bits as in lsb= least significant

Comment: I am on that part. What I don't know is the connections to the logic gates before connecting it to the magnitude comparator. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Your title says signed magnitude. So these are not twos complement? (Just want to be absolutely sure.)

Comment: Note that jonk's question is quite germane. Are you really willing to deal with the implications of having plus and minus zero?

Comment: Yes! I am comparing positive and negative values depending on the value of my signed bit.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for the solution to this problem myself, and then realised the answer.

With a normal binary comparator, all bits have a positive assigned value, bit 0 is 1, bit 1 is 2, etc.
So, with 5 bits, bit 4 would be 16.
Dealing with signed numbers, using the 2's complement, the last bit is just the negative value of whatever it should be, in this case, instead of 16, it's -16.

Since you're only interested if one value is larger than the other, or if they're equal to each other, the actual values don't matter, so you'd want to turn every number positive for simplicity, by adding the largest negative value to the number, in this case, add 16 to it.

Well, add a not gate to the sign bit, then treat it as the MSB, and it works!

Example:
if the number is 0, you have 00000, this becomes 10000, 16, you added 16.
if the number is -16, you have 10000, this becomes 00000, 0, you added 16.
if the number is 8, you have 01000, this becomes 11000, 24, you added 16.
if the number is -8, you have 11000, this becomes 01000, 8, you added 16.

so by simply adding a not gate to the input of the MSB (or signed bit), you convert all the numbers back to positive numbers, offset by the largest negative number, and can use a normal 5 bit comparator.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) ways to represent signed binary.  Each has advantages for different useage.

- 1's complement,  ( simple but has a +/-0)
- 2's complement, (invert and add 1, better for carry operations)
- offset binary, (biased so it is monotonic in binary and decimal then zero=10000...)

Once you decide which source representation then you can convert to the standard notiation required for the SN7485N in straight binary or BCD as you wish.

Which source representation did you mean?

Comment: I am comparing positive and negative values depending on the value of my signed bit. So I think 2's compliment is more applicable